# After Form Submit, Replace Content With Message Using PHP Only

Tags: php, forms

I have a popup that contains a subscriber sign up form. After the user clicks subscribe I want the form be removed and display a thank you message. All this needs to run using php.

Below is what I have so far, but the popup doesn't stay up and when clicking on the subscribe button again it shows the form validation errors because the 'subscribeSubmit' variable is set.

So, how keep the popup open and replace the form with the welcome message?

Please help, thanks!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['subscribeSubmit'])){

unset($error); //errasing error variable


//**************finding errors in form*******************  

if(strlen($_POST['Fname']) <= 0) {$error[] = "Your name is required.";}

if(!eregi("^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$", stripslashes(trim($_POST['emailPopin'])))) {$error[] = "Your e-mail address is not valid.";}

if(strlen($_POST['emailPopin']) <= 5) {$error[] = "You have to enter at least one e-mail to subscribe.";}

if(strlen($_POST['industry']) <= 0) {$error[] = "Your industry is required.";}

if(strlen($_POST['country']) <= 0) {$error[] = "Your country is required.";}

if(strlen($_POST['zip']) <= 0) {$error[] = "Your zip is required.";}

//************if there is an error**********

if(sizeof($error) > 0)
{
report_errors($error);
subscribe_form();                   
}

//**********if there is no error, we can subscribe them******  

else
{

//**********Reduce First Name to 30 characters and replace special characters******  

$name = substr($_POST['Fname'], 0, 30);

//***** Replaces special characters ******
$name = special_letters($name);


//**********write to data file******  

//Left out on purpose

//**********Display thank you message******

echo '<p>Thanks for signing up!<br/><a href="#" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Click here to sign up friends.</a></p>';

}

}

else

{ 

$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
$email = $_POST["emailPopin"];
$leader = $_POST["radiobuttonTeamLeader"];
$industry = $_POST["industry"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$zip = $_POST["zip"];


echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="background:#efefef;">';

echo '<div style="text-align:left;background:#efefef;padding-bottom:4px;"><p style="line-height:20px; font-size:12px;">Fill in the form below to signup for our free daily newsletter. All fields are Necessary.( <span class="required">*</span> ).</p><table id="popupSubscribe-form">';

echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="name">First Name: <span class="required">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" name="f_name" size="30" value=""></td></tr>';

echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="email">Email: <span class="required">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" size="30" id="emailPopin" value=""></td></tr>';

echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="email">I Lead A Team: <span class="required">*</span></label></td>';

echo '<td><table><tr><td><input type="radio" value="yes" name="radiobuttonTeamLeader" style="width:15px;"><strong style="margin: 0 15px 0 5px;">Yes</strong></td>';

echo '<td><input type="radio" value="no" name="radiobuttonTeamLeader" style="width:15px;"><strong style="margin: 0 15px 0 5px;">No</strong></td></tr></table></td>';

echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="industry">Industry: <span class="required">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" name="industry" size="30" value=""></td></tr>';

echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="country">Country <span class="required">*</span></label></td>';

echo '<td><select size="1" class="countryDropDown" name="country">';

echo '<option value="us" selected="selected">United States</option>';
echo '<option value="ca" >Canada</option>';

echo '</select></td></tr>';

echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="email">Zip Code: <span class="required">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" name="zip" size="30" value=""></td></tr>';

echo '<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" id="subscribeSubmit" value="" name="subscribeSubmit"/></td></tr></table></div>';



echo '</form>';

}

}
```

Comment: You say: `when clicking on the subscribe button again it shows the form validation errors`. So there are valid errors that are appearing? Or are you saying there are no actual errors and the errors section is appearing improperly?

Comment: No, there are not valid errors when submitting the form.

So what happens is. I fill out the form, click subscribe, and the pop up disappears instead of showing the thank you message. I then click the 'click here to subscribe' button that brings the popup form and it is showing the validation errors. 

This is caused because the isset($_POST['subscribeSubmit']) is set.

I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This isn't the code that you need to change. We need to see the `subscribe_form()` function. It seems to be the one that's closing the popup on you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're going for?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['subscribeSubmit'])){

    unset($error); //errasing error variable


    //**************finding errors in form*******************  

    if(strlen($_POST['Fname']) <= 0) {$error[] = "Your name is required.";}

    if(!eregi("^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$", stripslashes(trim($_POST['emailPopin'])))) {$error[] = "Your e-mail address is not valid.";}

    if(strlen($_POST['emailPopin']) <= 5) {$error[] = "You have to enter at least one e-mail to subscribe.";}

    if(strlen($_POST['industry']) <= 0) {$error[] = "Your industry is required.";}

    if(strlen($_POST['country']) <= 0) {$error[] = "Your country is required.";}

    if(strlen($_POST['zip']) <= 0) {$error[] = "Your zip is required.";}

    //************if there is an error**********

    if(sizeof($error) > 0)
    {
        report_errors($error);
        subscribe_form();                   
    }

    //**********if there is no error, we can subscribe them******  

    else
    {

        //**********Reduce First Name to 30 characters and replace special characters******  

        $name = substr($_POST['Fname'], 0, 30);

        //***** Replaces special characters ******
        $name = special_letters($name);


        //**********write to data file******  

        //Left out on purpose

        //**********Display thank you message******

        $thank_you_message = '<p>Thanks for signing up!<br/><a href="#" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Click here to sign up friends.</a></p>';

    }

    $Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
    $email = $_POST["emailPopin"];
    $leader = $_POST["radiobuttonTeamLeader"];
    $industry = $_POST["industry"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    $zip = $_POST["zip"];

}

if(!empty($thank_you_message)){
    echo $thank_you_message;
}else{

    echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="background:#efefef;">';

    echo '<div style="text-align:left;background:#efefef;padding-bottom:4px;"><p style="line-height:20px; font-size:12px;">Fill in the form below to signup for our free daily newsletter. All fields are Necessary.( <span class="required">*</span> ).</p><table id="popupSubscribe-form">';

    echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="name">First Name: <span class="required">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" name="f_name" size="30" value=""></td></tr>';

    echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="email">Email: <span class="required">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" size="30" id="emailPopin" value=""></td></tr>';

    echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="email">I Lead A Team: <span class="required">*</span></label></td>';

    echo '<td><table><tr><td><input type="radio" value="yes" name="radiobuttonTeamLeader" style="width:15px;"><strong style="margin: 0 15px 0 5px;">Yes</strong></td>';

    echo '<td><input type="radio" value="no" name="radiobuttonTeamLeader" style="width:15px;"><strong style="margin: 0 15px 0 5px;">No</strong></td></tr></table></td>';

    echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="industry">Industry: <span class="required">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" name="industry" size="30" value=""></td></tr>';

    echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="country">Country <span class="required">*</span></label></td>';

    echo '<td><select size="1" class="countryDropDown" name="country">';

    echo '<option value="us" selected="selected">United States</option>';
    echo '<option value="ca" >Canada</option>';

    echo '</select></td></tr>';

    echo '<tr><td class="label"><label for="email">Zip Code: <span class="required">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" name="zip" size="30" value=""></td></tr>';

    echo '<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" id="subscribeSubmit" value="" name="subscribeSubmit"/></td></tr></table></div>';

    echo '</form>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

subscribe_form(); is exactly the same as the form code above that is after the else/echo that displays the thank you message.

I tried to leave a comment, but apparently don't have enough user points and was not signed in when posting the question.